# Erro ao executar container (Docker) com browser-sync

Tags: node.js, docker

Recebo este aviso ao dar *start* no meu `container` com ***browser-sync***:

> ```
> [BS] Watching files... (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning:
> Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Exited with code
> 3
> ```

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Pode postar o seu Dockerfile?

Comment: Tenho o mesmo erro. É um warning do seu browser dizendo que não confia na fonte do site. Você pode viver com esse warning ou desabilitar no browser.

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Comment: Resolveu o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Sua aplicação está dando erro e parando e execução no nodejs,
como o docker vê que o seu node parou e não tem mais processos ele derruba o contêiner.

tente tratar o erro da aplicação

[este link](https://thecodebarbarian.com/unhandled-promise-rejections-in-node.js.html) pode te ajudar